# Find a row with value zero in any column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I’ve 10,000 rows with 64 columns.

If any column in any row has the value “0”, that row needs to be selected. Does anyone have a ready-made query? It would be a benefit to my project.

The values can be null. The value cannot be negative. It is an `int` value. The version is SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Too many variants:

```
WHERE column1=0 OR column2=0 OR ... OR column64=0
WHERE column1*column2* ... *column64=0
WHERE 0 IN (column1, column2, ... column64)
```

and so on...

Comment: The second method has the risk of overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

You  may try to generate a dynamic statement using data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and filter columns by data type or column name:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @err int
SET @stm = N''

-- Dymanic statement
SELECT @stm = 
    @stm + 
    CONCAT(
    N' OR (',
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    N'=0)'
    )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    DATA_TYPE IN ('int', 'numeric', 'decimal') AND
    -- Or filter by column name
    -- COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%% '
    TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'

SET @stm = CONCAT(
    N'SELECT * FROM [YourTableName] WHERE ', 
    STUFF(@stm, 1, 4, N'')
)

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
```